# Can someone explain me the following Hive (0.13) behavior?

Tags: hive, decimal, precision

```
select 52 * 20 / 6700000 ;
=0.00015522388059701492  
select cast(52 as decimal(2,0)) * 20 / 6700000;
=0.00015522
```

Why is precision ruined by using decimal?
It doesn't help to use a higher precision decimal, or cast as decimal all the members of the query, the result will stay only 8 digit precise.

Answer (score 0):

When working with floating point numbers, computers have to find a compromise between speed and precision. This shows especially when working with very small or very big floating point numbers.

There is a [IEEE standard on how languages should treat floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), so the error is "standardized" in a way.

Here is an interesting example, comparing multiple languages: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

When you tell the program to treat something not as a floating point number but as a decimal, the result changes as it won't comply to the standard anymore.

Comment: Interesting articles, but regretfully none of them gives any answer to the question: decimal() simply shouldn't work this way, but apperently it does. So the question remains: anyone with any idea why? Anyone met the same problem in Hive 0.13?

Answer (score -1):

In case 1, hive returns double so you are seeing a really large precision.The range of decimal type is approximately -10^-308 to 10^308.

```
select 52 * 20 / 6700000 ;
Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:_c0, type:double, comment:null)], properties:null)
```

In case 2, hive returns decimal(12,8) so you see such result.

```
select cast(52 as decimal(2,0)) * 20 / 6700000; 
Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:_c0, type:decimal(12,8), comment:null)], properties:null)
```

Why? I am not 100% sure but i think in case 1, hive is trying to return default data type but in case 2 since we are using cast decimal so its trying to return in decimal(12,8). I ran SQLs and captured internal log to show the return data type.